# What is the definition of moderator for the engagement survey?

Tags: discussion, moderator-satisfaction-survey

I got the "Moderator Engagement survey" email, however I'm pretty sure I'm not a moderator on any Stack Exchange site, given I don't have diamond beside my username. Is the definition of moderator for this survey different than "diamond beside username"? Does it have to do with a certain reputation threshold?

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSO: [Why am I getting the Moderator Engagement survey?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371881/559745)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gather that this was an error in e-mail distribution. According to [the first July 2018 moderator newsletter](https://stackmod.blog/2018/07/july-2018-newsletter/) (and to a lesser extent [the second one](https://stackmod.blog/2018/07/july-2018-newsletter-ii/)), these are indeed intended for people who fit the "typical" definition of moderator: elected or appointed diamond on at least one of the network sites.

Answer (score 7):

I received a follow-up email apologizing for the error. Consequently, @SOLO's answer is indeed correct and I am not a moderator.